# Server 2012 Remote Desktop Services, Foxit Reader as default

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, windows-registry, pdf, defaults

I have a Server 2012 RDS server I'm setting up. I have installed Foxit Reader. I then went to the registry and set the value of HKLM\Software\Classes\ .pdf to FoxitReader.Document. I also set up a group policy preference to set the value for HKCU\Software\Classes\ .pdf to FoxitReader.Document. I know they're related, but I double checked that HKCR was set to Foxit properly as well.

When I log into the server I have pdf documents on the desktop. They have the Foxit icon. They open in Foxit. Foxit then says it is not the default, would I like to make it the default? This leads to UAC prompts and other annoyances.

I have 2 questions. Am I missing something within Server 2012 to set default programs for file extensions? This has been straight forward in the past. Secondly, where the flip-flop does Foxit look for when it does a default check?